# How to get validation arguments class provided by a class with PowerSell

Tags: powershell, class

I would just like to get the validation arguments provided by an IValidateSetValuesGenerator class similar to a return when we use a bad argument (see example command Sample -Verb 'BadVerb')

Below is an example of code:

```
class verb : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator
{
    [String[]] GetValidValues()
    {
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Verbs = @()
        $VerbsSource = Get-Verb

        foreach ($Verb in $VerbsSource)
        {
            $Verbs.Add([PSCustomObject]@{'verb' = $Verb.Verb})
        }

        return ($Verbs).Verb
    }
}


function Sample
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, 
                  PositionalBinding=$false,
                  ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([bool])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateSet([verb], ErrorMessage="Value '{0}' is invalid. Try one of: {1}")]
        [string]$Verb
    )
    Begin
    {

    }
    Process
    {

    }
    End
    {
        return $Verb
    }
}

Sample -Verb 'BadVerb'
Sample -Verb 'Get'
```

Comment: `[verb]::new().GetValidValues()` should do the trick

Comment: As an aside (I understand that your example may just be a trimmed-down, simplified version of more complex code): As written, the body of your `GetValidValues()` method can be simplified to: `return (Get-Verb).Verb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [mklement0's excellent explanation of `[Verb]::new()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68022186/712649), allow me to provide you with an example of how you could structure the value generator class so that you don't need an instance to generate the values:

```
class verb : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator
{
    [String[]] GetValidValues()
    {
        return [Verb]::GetValidValues()
    }
    
    static [String[]] GetValidValues()
    {
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Verbs = @()
        $VerbsSource = Get-Verb

        foreach ($Verb in $VerbsSource)
        {
            $Verbs.Add([PSCustomObject]@{'verb' = $Verb.Verb})
        }

        return ($Verbs).Verb
    }
}
```

Now we've moved the actual heavy lifting to a `static` method, and the instance method (which is what PowerShell is going to call) simply calls the static method.

Now you can get the value list without creating an instance of `[verb]`:

```
PS ~> [verb]::GetValidValues()
```

Comment: I can't use static with GetValidValues, I can with another name. If I use PowerShell return this error:
````Error during creation of type "Verb". Error message: Method 'GetValidValues' in type Verb' from assembly 'PowerShell | Class Assembly, Version=1.0.0.43, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.````

Comment: @Xenixium look at the answer again - you need both a static and a non-static version of GetValidValues()

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer:

```sh
# PSv5+ syntax: 
# Construct (create an instance of) the [verb] class and call its
# .GetValidValues() instance method.
[verb]::new().GetValidValues() # Returns a [string[]] array of valid values.
```

---

Your `[verb]` [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) implements the [`[System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator) interface (for use in [`[ValidateSet]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute) attributes to allow constraining parameter values to a dynamically generated set of valid (permissible) values).

This interface, has a single *instance* method, `.GetValidValues()`, which returns the permissible values, and which PowerShell calls behind the scenes during parameter validation.

Therefore, in order to call this method yourself, **you need to create an *instance* of your `[verb]` class first**:

- In PowerShell v5+, the best choice is to use the **static `::new()` method**, which is **PowerShell's way of exposing public *constructors***; that is, `[verb]::new()` is equivalent to `new verb()` in C#.
- In **older PowerShell versions** you must use the **[`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) cmdlet** for calling constructors; the equivalent of `[verb]::new()` is `New-Object verb`

```sh
# PowerShell v5+
[verb]::new().GetValidValues()

# PowerShell v4-, but also works in higher versions.
(New-Object verb).GetValidValues()
```

**Syntax pitfalls**:

**`::new()` uses *method syntax*** (as in C#), whereas **`New-Object`, as a cmdlet, uses *command syntax***,<sup>[1]</sup> i.e. is invoked like a *shell command*: no `(...)` around the list of arguments, *whitespace* as the argument separator.

The following example - using a constructor with arguments - illustrates the difference:

```sh
# PSv5+ ::new() call - method syntax.
# Equivalent of this C# constructor call:
#   new Regex("^\w+=.+", RegexOptions.Multiline, new Timespan(1000));
[regex]::new('^\w+=.+', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline, [timespan]:new(1000))

# Equivalent New-Object call - command syntax,
# using verbose *named* parameter binding.
# Note the following:
#  * absence of (...) around the list of arguments as a whole
#  * use of whitespace to separate arguments (and also parameter names from their arguments)
#  * the need to separate the *constructor* arguments with ","
#    as they must be passed as an *array*.
#  * the need to enclose [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline individually in (...)
New-Object -TypeName regex -ArgumentList '^\w+=.+', ([System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)

# Equivalent call using *positional* (unnamed) parameter binding.
New-Object regex  '^\w+=.+', ([System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)
```

A **particular pitfall** is when a **constructor takes a *single* argument that is an *array*** or a collection, which **with `New-Object` requires wrapping the array in an *aux., transitory array***:

```sh
$array = 1, 2

# OK: Initialize an ArrayList instance via an array that
#     binds as a whole to the `System.Collections.ICollection c`
#     constructor parameter.
[System.Collections.ArrayList]::new($array)

# !! BROKEN
# $array is interpreted as *multiple* (two separate) arguments.
New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList -ArgumentList $array

# OK
# Need to wrap the array in an aux. transitory array.
New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList -ArgumentList (, $array)
```

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell terms, method syntax is parsed in *expression mode*, whereas command syntax is parsed in *argument mode*. See the conceptual [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) help topic.</sup>