# What is Add-Type vs square bracket?

Tags: powershell, syntax, constructor

To use a .net type, I normally do `Add-Type` then use `New-Object`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
$win = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
```

But really I can also just use square bracket syntax to refer the type and use static methods:

```
$win = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
```

What's the difference between them? I have not found much documentation with square bracket syntax for .Net types. All documentation I found for square brackets are for the arrays.

Comment: You can use the 2nd option tho it requires PS 5.1+ I think

Comment: the 2nd method is faster and rather more obvious when reading the code. `New-Object` and `Add-Member` are both known to be quite slow.

Comment: Using the `new()` static method is faster, but not just that, when you enter such method to create an object without the brackets, you can see all overloaded constructor definitions (if there are any..) to help you choose. Try for instance `[datetime]::new` and hit enter. P.S. I wouldn't use `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName()` anymore as it is [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadwithpartialname?view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadWithPartialName_System_String_)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) is only used to *load* .NET types into a session (or to *define* them by ad hoc compilation).

To *use* these types by calling their *constructors*, you have two options:

- In *any* PowerShell version:

  - Call the [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) *cmdlet*.
- Preferably, in PowerShell **v5+**:

  - Use a *type literal* (`[...]`) and call the type's (PowerShell-supplied) static `::new()` method.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375) for more information about PowerShell type literals.

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) and [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) note, using the static `::new()` method has several advantages:

- Calling `::new()` is *faster*; with a single or only a few constructor calls that probably won't matter, but it may in loops.
- Executing just `::new` *without parentheses* shows all constructor *overloads*, which is a convenient way to find out what constructor *arguments* are needed and what their types are.
- Calling `::new()` doesn't wrap the newly created instance in a - mostly - invisible `[psobject]` wrapper, the way that `New-Object` and cmdlets in general do; while this wrapper is mostly benign, it can cause subtle differences in behavior - see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).

Note that, due to PowerShell's two fundamental [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), `New-Object` and `::new()` require *different syntax*, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68022186/45375).